# Swap between multiple webrtc streams in MediaRecorder

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, webrtc, mediarecorder

I'm planning on creating a browser application that will take in multiple webrtc streams from mobile device cameras and record them using the browser mediarecorder API.

The trick is I want the browser UI to be able to switch between the various streams real time as the video is recorded, in effect allowing a multi camera set up for a live event. The output would then be piped to ffmpeg.

The cameras would all be streaming via RTCPeerConnection to a central browser client, which would do the "switching".

Is it possible to have a button listener that can switch between streams to the media recorder?

Comment: Are you planning on using `RTCPeerConnection`, or are all the cameras local to the browser client? Please clarify in the question.

Comment: @jib Yes, I they will be using RTCPeerConnection. Question updated.